# $5$ real numbers tied by two equations: understanding a proof of the related problem.

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, proof-explanation, real-numbers

> If $a,b,c,d,e$ are real numbers such that
>   $$
>    \left\{
>    \begin{array}{lcl}
>      \phantom{0}40-e  &=&  a+b+c+d, \\
>              400-e^2  &=&  a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2,
>    \end{array}
>    \right.
> $$
>   find $\max(e)$.

In the solution provided, I don't understand equation $(1)$:

> We know that
>   \begin{align*}
>      (40-e)^2
>   &= (a+b+c+d)^2 \\
>   &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd).
> \end{align*}
>   Now note that $2xy\leq x^2+y^2$ for all reals $x,y$. Hence
>   $$
>   (40-e)^2 \leq 4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2).
>   \tag{1}
> $$

I understand why $2xy\leq x^2+y^2$, but I'm not sure how the author derives the above inequality. $4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$ doesn't seem to represent the sum of two squares. The way the proof is worded so far implies this is obvious, so I think I'm clearly missing something.  An explanation as to why the above inequality is true would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is using it for $$2ab \leq a^2+b^2$$ $$2ac \leq a^2+c^2$$ $$2ad \leq a^2+d^2$$ $$2bc \leq b^2+c^2$$ $$2bd \leq b^2+d^2$$ and $$2cd \leq c^2+d^2$$

Comment: As per your answer, summing all these inequalities yields $$3(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\geq 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$$ so $$(40-e)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)\leq 4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$$ For a continuation, we know that $4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)=4(400-e^2)=1600-4e^2, $ hence $1600-80-e^2\leq 1600-4e^2$. So $5e^2\leq 80e\implies e\leq 16$. Therefore, $\max(e)=16$. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: Apart from some little typos, it is correct. But it only proves $e \leq 16$, in order to prove $max(e)=16$ you should also provide some $(a,b,c,d,e)$ for which $e=16$ and the other two equalities are satisfied.

Comment: You're right, $a=b=c=d=6$ works.

Answer (score 0):

You must write $$2ab\le a^2+b^2$$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following way is much more better.

By C-S $$400-e^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=\frac{1}{4}(1+1+1+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{4}(a+b+c+d)^2=\frac{1}{4}(40-e)^2,$$
which gives $0\leq e\leq16.$

The equality occurs for $(a,b,c,d,e)=(6,6,6,6,16),$ which says that $16$ is a maximal value.

Comment: There's also a neat solution using Jensen, but this is cool!

Comment: Yes, Jensen for $f(x)=x^2.$